# Css não encontrado página html - SpringFramework

Tags: java, css, spring-mvc

Olá.

Estou com problemas em obter os css, js, fonts etc do meu projeto em minhas páginas. Estou usando Spring, digitando o endereço dos arquivos css no browser mas o sistema não está conseguindo achar corretamente o caminho. 
Se alguém puder ajudar..

**Estrutura de pastas do Projeto**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**application-context.xml**

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.gervasios.sgr" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="index"/>

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
    </bean>

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" cache-period="120"/>

    <mvc:default-servlet-handler />
```

**web.xml**

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         metadata-complete="true" version="3.0">
    <display-name>sgr-application</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Spring-Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/application-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Spring-Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**login.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Login</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/fonts/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/css/animate.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/css/login.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/css/custom.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/css/icheck/flat/green.css">

    <script src="/resources/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body style="background:#F7F7F7;">
   //codigos.....
   //codigos.....
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Retirado deste link:**

http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-how-to-include-js-or-css-files-in-a-jsp-page/

1 - Coloque seus arquivos estáticos nessa pasta webapp\resources

2 - Crie o mapping do spring

3 - Inclua o link na view via JSTL tag `c:url` ou Spring tag `spring:url`

**Spring Resource Mapping**

No seu arquivo de configuração você irá mapear onde estará seus estáticos:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/seus-estaticos/" />
```

**Incluindo na view**

Com JSTL tag

```
<head>
    <link href="<c:url value="/resources/css/main.css" />" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="<c:url value="/resources/js/jquery.1.10.2.min.js" />"></script>
    <script src="<c:url value="/resources/js/main.js" />"></script>
</head>
```

Com sprint tag

```
<head>
    <spring:url value="/resources/css/main.css" var="mainCss" />
    <spring:url value="/resources/js/jquery.1.10.2.min.js" var="jqueryJs" />
    <spring:url value="/resources/js/main.js" var="mainJs" />

    <link href="${mainCss}" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="${jqueryJs}"></script>
    <script src="${mainJs}"></script>
</head>
```

Espero ter ajudado! :D

Comment: Obrigado Daniel Beff, mudei para .jsp minhas páginas e fiz conforme descreveu. Deu tudo certo.

Comment: De nada! Fico feliz de ter ajudado!